# Populate state and city based on the entered zip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, closest

I have form where used can enter zip code and based on that City and State will be automatically populated. So these three fields are in the same form next to each other. Here is example of my form:

```js
$('.get-zip').keyup(getZipCode);
function getZipCode(){
    var fldZip = $(this);
    
    console.log($(this).closest('.form-group'));
   
    if(fldZip.val().length === 5 && fldZip.val().match(/^[0-9]+$/)) {
        //Send Ajax request and populate closest State and City fields.
    }else{
        //$(cityID).val('');
        //$(stateID).val('');
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form name="frmSave" id="frmSave" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="city"><span class="label label-primary">City:</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control city" name="frm_city" id="frm_city" maxlength="50" placeholder="City auto populate based on the zip code" readonly>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="state"><span class="label label-primary">State:</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control state" name="frm_state" id="frm_state" maxlength="2" placeholder="State auto populate based on the zip code" readonly>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="zip"><span class="label label-primary">Zip:</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control get-zip" name="frm_zip" id="frm_zip" maxlength="5" placeholder="Enter 5 digits ZIP code" pattern="[0-9]{5}$" required>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <button type="submit" name="frm_submit" id="frm_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div id="frmSave_message"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

This function is used in few other forms in my application so I need this to work in any form. I'm wondering what is the easiest way to populate State and City that are above Zip input field? I tried to use `closest()` but that won't work since I need to specify which input exactly I need to populate. If anyone have better idea on how to achieve this please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to populate exactly? Are you trying to replace the Label tags with what the user is typing?

Comment: @GrandIQ If you look at my example you will see two input fields. One for state and one for city. Those two should be populated. So I need to get `id` of each element so I can populate the values.

Comment: You can assign a state id="state" and another id for city id="city'. This way you can target them with jquery? Then populate the data to each one accordingly.

Comment: $(this).closest('.form-group') will select the parent form-group. Try selecting the closest form and then traverse down to the form groups
 $form_group = $(this).closest('form').find('.form-group');
 $form_group.find('input.city').val(city);
 $form_group.find('input.state').val(state);

Comment: @GrandIQ I already mentioned in my question above that this function should work on multiple form in the system where `id's` might be different so I should use `state` and `city` class to populate these values.

Comment: Okay I see what your trying to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will always post to the nearest input forms of state and city!
Hope I helped!

```js
$('.get-zip').keyup(getZipCode);
function getZipCode(){
    var fldZip = $(this);
 
    // Testing Purpose
    $(this).closest("form").find(".state").val($(this).val());
    $(this).closest("form").find(".city").val($(this).val());
   
    if(fldZip.val().length === 5 && fldZip.val().match(/^[0-9]+$/)) {
        
       $(this).closest("form").find(".state").val("YOUR VALUE");
       $(this).closest("form").find(".city").val("YOUR VALUE");

    }else{
        //$(cityID).val('');
        //$(stateID).val('');
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form name="frmSave" id="frmSave" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="city"><span class="label label-primary">City:</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control city" name="frm_city" id="frm_city" maxlength="50" placeholder="City auto populate based on the zip code" readonly>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="state"><span class="label label-primary">State:</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control state" name="frm_state" id="frm_state" maxlength="2" placeholder="State auto populate based on the zip code" readonly>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="zip"><span class="label label-primary">Zip:</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control get-zip" name="frm_zip" id="frm_zip" maxlength="5" placeholder="Enter 5 digits ZIP code" pattern="[0-9]{5}$" required>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <button type="submit" name="frm_submit" id="frm_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div id="frmSave_message"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following may work as long as all the different forms have the elements arranged in the same way.

[jQuery .prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)

[jQuery .find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
var stateFormGroup = $(this).closest('.form-group').prev();
var stateElement = stateFormGroup.find('input');
var cityElement = stateFormGroup.prev().find('input');
```

Comment: He wants it to also work on other forums, I am assuming they might be on the same page so we can't use the same ID

Comment: @GrandIQ You are right, they are on the same page and they have different id's.

Comment: That makes sense, I misread the question sorry. Even if this won't work for this scenario, I believe something will need to be the same across the different forms for this to work. If the IDs are not the some, would they share a common class? If not you could something like .closest('.form-group').prev() to get the previous sibling element. https://api.jquery.com/prev/

Comment: @GabrielGates Is there any difference in efficiency between your solution and one with the `closest()` method? In the meantime I found solution and I used `prev()` and `parent()` methods to get desired elements.

Comment: @espresso_coffee can't say for certain as I don't know the semantics of jQuery, if you're comparing mine to the .closest('form') answer, conceptually one could say there is less traversing of elements with my solution. Also to optimize further, you could create more variables, I'll update my answer to show what I mean.

Comment: I do like the fact that you used prev(), only reason why I used the closest and back to the form is because he said he has different forms, that way I can guarantee I am landing on the correct input.

Comment: I used .closest() as well, which will guarantee to select the form-group inside any form. I suppose if not all of @espresso_coffee's forms wrapped the inputs in an element with the '.form-group' class, it wouldn't work properly.

Comment: @espresso_coffee `.parent()` will work as long as the `.form-group` element is the immediate parent. Not sure whether it's more efficient than `.closest()` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Posting the comment here as answer.

`$(this).closest('.form-group')` will select the parent form-group. Try selecting the closest form and then traverse down to the form groups.

```
$form_group = $(this).closest('form').find('.form-group'); 
$form_group.find('input.city').val(city); 
$form_group.find('input.state').val(state);
```